# Where does 5e Warlock Fey Presence AoE take effect

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, area-of-effect

The PHB definition for Fey Presence has the term **10-foot cube originating from you**, but since a character occupies a 5 foot square, it is hard to say which squares on the grid are affected. Usually self-origin spell and features use radius, cone, or shapes that have a center, like a 15 foot square would...

> Your patron bestows upon you the ability to project the beguiling and fearsome presence of the fey. As an action, you can cause each creature in a 10-foot cube originating from you to make a Wisdom saving throw against your warlock spell save DC. The creatures that fail their saving throws are all charmed or frightened by you (your choice) until the end of your next turn. Once you use this feature, you can't use it again until you finish a short or long rest.

Anyone know how this should be played?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHB p204 (Emphasis Mine)

> **Cube** You select a cube’s point of origin, which lies anywhere on a
>   face of the cubic effect. The cube’s size is expressed as the length
>   of each side. A cube’s point of origin is not included in the cube’s
>   area of effect, unless you decide otherwise.

So in essence you choose a 10x10x10 and as long as one of the sides/corners is adjacent to you (or includes you should you so choose.), you are doing it correctly.